# How to solve overflow errors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have looked online for this and have even tried to solve overflow through `SingleChildScrollView`. But it isn't working unfortunately. It keeps giving me an error and says that the Google sign in Button has overflowed 154 pixels to the right. What is the best solution for this? I appreciate anyone that tries to help in any way. I am a bit of a beginner to Flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth_buttons/flutter_auth_buttons.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(LandingPage());
}

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // This takes you to Google Login Button stateful widget
      home: GoogleLoginBtn()
    );
  }
}


final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  return user;
}


// Just created a stateful widget
// This represents a login button
class GoogleLoginBtn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<GoogleLoginBtn> {

  FirebaseUser user;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(166),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('ProtoX',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 360,
                  width: 360,
                ),
               GoogleSignInButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                   _handleSignIn()
                       .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
                       .catchError((e) => print(e));
                    // Transition to Homepage page

                 },
               ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding the exact error and maybe a screenshot would be helpful. Do you understand what the error is saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EdgeInsets.all(166)` , `166` could be a typo. you can change to `16`

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth_buttons/flutter_auth_buttons.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(LandingPage());
}

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        // This takes you to Google Login Button stateful widget
        home: GoogleLoginBtn());
  }
}

final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  return user;
}

// Just created a stateful widget
// This represents a login button
class GoogleLoginBtn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<GoogleLoginBtn> {
  FirebaseUser user;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'ProtoX',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 360,
                  width: 360,
                ),
                GoogleSignInButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _handleSignIn()
                        .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
                        .catchError((e) => print(e));
                    // Transition to Homepage page
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```